# How can Iinux powershell test if a file is a symbolic link?

Tags: linux, powershell

On Linux, I want to replace a bash script with powershell. The script needs to test a file to determine if it is a symbolic link. In bash, one can use the `-L` operator:

`if [[ -L "/tmp/mysteryfile" ]] ; then ; echo "It is a link" ; fi`

How can I do the same in powershell on Linux?

Comment: Look at the attributes of the file, there a plenty of indicators that it is a symlink.   `Get-ChildItem filename | Format-List *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Ubuntu 19.04 this:

```
PS> gci /bin/bz*|select Mode,LastWriteTime,Length,Name,Attributes,LinkType|ft -auto
```

yields

```
Mode   LastWriteTime     Length Name           Attributes LinkType
----   -------------     ------ ----           ---------- --------
--r--l 04.07.19 14:50:14  38984 bzcat            ReadOnly HardLink
-----l 04.07.19 14:50:14      6 bzcmp        ReparsePoint SymbolicLink
--r--- 04.07.19 14:50:14   2227 bzdiff           ReadOnly 
-----l 04.07.19 14:50:14      6 bzegrep      ReparsePoint SymbolicLink
--r--- 13.08.18 13:29:27   4877 bzexe            ReadOnly 
-----l 04.07.19 14:50:14      6 bzfgrep      ReparsePoint SymbolicLink
--r--- 04.07.19 14:50:14   3641 bzgrep           ReadOnly 
--r--l 04.07.19 14:50:14  38984 bzip2            ReadOnly HardLink
--r--- 04.07.19 14:50:14  14328 bzip2recover     ReadOnly 
-----l 04.07.19 14:50:14      6 bzless       ReparsePoint SymbolicLink
--r--- 04.07.19 14:50:14   1297 bzmore           ReadOnly
```

So the Mode `l` denotes a link, as does the Attribute `ReparsePoint` denote a SymbolicLink.

But only the LinkType differentiates between Hard-/SymbolicLinks

```
if((Get-Item "/tmp/mysteryfile").LinkType -eq 'SymbolicLink'){"It is a SymbolicLink"}
```

or

```
if($LT=(Get-Item "/tmp/mysteryfile").LinkType){"It is a $LT"}
```

To see some stats:

```
PS> gci /bin -rec -force -ea 0|Where LinkType|Group LinkType -NoElement               

Count Name
----- ----
    3 HardLink
  276 SymbolicLink
```